# C# - handling WPF usercontrol events in winforms

Tags: c#, wpf

I am hosting a WPF usercontrol in winform. I am using WPF control Expander in WPF usercontrol(**UserControl1**). When i expand or collapse the expander my mainform should get notified. How to achive this?

I tried with the following options:

- Declared a delegate and event in userconttol1 and tried to subscribe in mainform - doesn't help
- used childchanged event in mainform

WPF usercontrol name - usercontrol1
Mainform Name - Form 1
hosted usercontrol in main form name - elementHost1

```
this.elementHost1.ChildChanged += new System.EventHandler<System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ChildChangedEventArgs>(this.elementHost1_ChildChanged);//form1 designer


        private void elementHost1_ChildChanged(object sender, ChildChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var ctr = (elementHost1.Child as UserControl1);
            if (ctr == null)
                return;
            ctr.isCollapsed+=new UserControl1.expandedDel(ctr_isCollapsed);

        }

    void ctr_isCollapsed(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

This solution doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

WPF usercontrol Winforms interop - handling WPF events in Winforms

Requirement: WPF usercontrol(UserControl1) contains Expander(expander1) and expander contains 3 radio buttons
and WPF usercontrl hosted in winform(Form1)
when radio button changed in usercontrol main form should get notifed and based on selection it should popup some controls in mainform

Code:in usercontrol1.xaml.cs

```
    public delegate void ucRadioButtonHandler(object sender, **ucButtonEventArgs** e);
    public event ucRadioButtonHandler onRadioButtonClick;

    private void radioButton1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (onRadioButtonClick != null)
        {
            onRadioButtonClick(sender, new ucButtonEventArgs());
        }
    }
```

ucButtonEventArgs is a class defined in same usercontrol.xaml.cs

```
public partial class ucButtonEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ucButtonEventArgs()
    {
    }
}
```

Now in MainForm Form1

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
            userControl11.onRadioButtonClick += new           WpfControlLibrary1.UserControl1.ucRadioButtonHandler(userControl11_onRadioButtonClick);
        }

 void userControl11_onRadioButtonClick(object sender, WpfControlLibrary1.ucButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Controls.RadioButton rb = (System.Windows.Controls.RadioButton)sender;
            MessageBox.Show(rb.Content + " Selected!!!!!!!!");
        }
```